# What do I need to do to submit my desktop app to the Windows Store?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc, windows-store-apps

[I heard](http://www.engadget.com/2015/04/29/desktop-apps-are-coming-to-the-windows-store/) that Windows 10 will allow developers to submit their desktop (non-Metro) apps to the Windows Store. I'm developing using C/C++/MFC and WinAPIs.

What do I need to do to submit my desktop app to the store? And what are the requirements/charge?

Comment: It's too early to answer this question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I thought they would announce it during the `Build Conference` that's happening now.

Comment: Very unlikely to happen this far out. When there's an answer to be had, it will be on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider watching [this //build talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692) with John Sheehan. It covers the details of Win32 apps in the store (codename *Project Centennial*). The first detail is "this project is still under development" (as of May 2015).

In a nutshell, you can take an existing MSI-based installed app, run it through a tool to generate an appx, and then you're done. There are some things that won't work (eg installing services, custom licensing / DRM, or running as administrator) but most normal app code will work. The example shown is Adobe PhotoShop Elements, which worked perfectly except for the licensing check (which can now be handled by the Store anyway).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting though, that is the concept of the `.app packages` on OS X. But if it works there, this sounds like a _band-aid_ on Windows. Unless you have a "Hello World" type app, I doubt it would be as smooth as he promised there. It is also amazing to me what Microsoft likes to do to their developers -- first they introduce "the best & greatest new concept" in Windows N, and then totally renege on it in Windows N+1.

Comment: It's not helpful to have an answer with no information that is just a link to an off site resource. Please provide a summary in addition to the link.

Comment: Any update on this guys since Windows 10 is officially out?

Comment: No update. I am sure there will be a news cycle when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sit through an hour of [this Build 2015 presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692) linked by [Peter Torr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30024707/843732), here's a synopsis of what *Project Centennial* will entail. Also, as was pointed out already, this is all a preliminary stuff, that is still under development (as of May 2015.)

Applies to Win32/.NET/COM based apps listed in a Windows 10 Store:

- MSIs are "evil". Use APPX packages instead.
- APPX Gloal: one-click installs thru Windows Store, automatic app updates via Windows Store (using *file diff*'ing - no need to re-download large unchanged files in the package.)
- Microsoft will have an automatic conversion tool: MSI to APPX.
- MSI licensing/DRM **will not** work: i.e. can't look up CPU serial number, hard drive info, network card MAC addr, etc. (*My take: The store app will not be able to access hardware directly.*)
- The app will have a live tile & anything else that can be done with the Universal App (or Metro style app.)
- The app's `AppxManifest.xml` file will define app's file associations.
- The app installs into a sandbox folder with randomized path, example: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\<GUID>\<Package Name>`. This path changes every time a new app version is released.
- The app's sandbox folder will have `Root\VFS` subfolder that will contain the following redirected subfolders:

  - `AppData`
  - `AppVSystem32Catroot`
  - `AppVSystem32Catroot2`
  - `Common AppData`
  - `ProgramFilesCommonX64`
  - `ProgramFilesCommonX86`
  - `System`
  - `SystemX86`
  - `Windows`

For instance, if your app tries to access `C:\Windows` it will be redirected to `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\<GUID>\<Package Name>\Root\VFS\Windows` invisibly for the app.

- The app's package sandbox folder will have `Registry.dat` file (that is a registry hive) for that app. All requests to the system registry done by your app will be redirected to that file, including `HKLM` and `HKCU` keys. So in other words, your app **won't** be able to modify any of the shared system registry keys.
- Apps installed via APPX packages cannot share dependencies between their files, nor inter-load other app's package contents.
- Namespace merging (between shared system files and package's `Root\VFS` folder files):

[image]

- Namespace wrire redirection (writing into shared system registry is redirected into your app's `Registry.dat` file. Also on the file system scale only `AppData` folder is redirected to your app's `Root\VFS\AppData` folder):

[image]

- The redirected `AppData` folder will be placed into non-roaming location.
- The store app can run **only as a user** (which they refer to as a "*Full Trust*", which in my book is a misnomer) It **cannot** run elevated, and if it tries to call an API that shows [UAC prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), such API will silently fail.
- The store app **cannot** install or run NT services.

I believe that there's a way to [sign up](https://projectipreviewsignup.windows.com/) for any updates on this project.

Comment: Great transcript, thanks! But no mention about the release date. Not even a month or a quarter. The speaker did not mention it, nobody asked a question... And there is no any info over the Internet (just a mention that the release was not included into VS 2015 because it was not ready and will be released as a separate set of tools).

Comment: @Mar: It seems like they scrapped it. The [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn374788(v=vs.85).aspx) I originally saved with the info, no longer works.

Comment: Great info! How do I specify default registry entries when I generate my appx? I can't find any info on this.

Comment: @JamesHancock: You don't do it manually. It's all done by the [Project Centennial converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for you.

Comment: I don't want to use the converter because it takes forever and is generating a ton of junk so I'm using the manual method and the only documentation I can't find is how to do the registry entries. Everything else is working flawlessly.

Comment: @JamesHancock: Sorry can't help you there. Btw, finding that Win32/UWP stuff is very difficult. There are not many people who know it. (If you want [email me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/843732/c00000fd?tab=profile), we can coordinate resources.) As for generating junk -- I understand you from a C/Win32 developer's standpoint -- otherwise why would you care? That code will be hosted on Microsoft servers anyway.

Comment: For those that might run into this article, the way of doing registry updates is to create a .reg file with all of your keys that you want included. Then use the reg tool to generate the .dat (there are command line flags). When you can include the registry.dat file created in your package and it will work properly.