# Windows App Certification Kit for Windows 7 application

Tags: windows, certificate

### Background

I have developed a desktop application which runs on Windows 7 SP1 x64 and potentially newer OS, but for now I'd like to release it for Windows 7. It is not available for Windows Phone nor is it available in a store. It's a good old standalone program, no cloud, nothing special.

At the moment I have some trouble, because the tool says

> The Windows App Certification Kit did not detect any new applications as a result of your installation.
>
> Testing cannot continue unless an application is successfully installed.
>
> Please confirm that your installer worked correctly and run the Windows App Certification Kit again.

I'm working on that and I hope this will finally not be related to the question.

### My Research

From the statement

> The Windows App Certification Kit now supports the following app types: Desktop apps for Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7

on [Windows App Certification Kit](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/app-certification-kit), my impression is that Windows 7 is supported.

However, on [Using the Windows App Certification Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx), Windows 7 is only mentioned in a weird scenario of testing a Windows 10 app on Windows 7.

The website [Certification requirements for Windows desktop apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx) talks about "Windows 8.1 Desktop App Certification" and refers to Windows 7 only for the name change:

> [...] in order to participate in the Windows 8.1 Desktop App Certification Program. For Windows 7, this program was known as the Windows Software Logo Program.

### The Question

Can a Windows 7 desktop application still get certified?

Answer (score 0):

related:
[What do I need to do to submit my desktop app to the Windows Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021501/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-submit-my-desktop-app-to-the-windows-store)

The main advantage to get a desktop application certified is that it can appear on Windows store.

Windows 7 cannot access Windows store, therefore it's pointless as far as Windows 7 users are concerned.

Windows 8 can access the app store, but it doesn't really work for desktop apps. User must exit desktop-mode and enter tablet-mode, go to Windows store, find the desktop app. But the desktop app will only appear as a link to developer's website. User must go back to desktop mode, go to the link and finally install...

Windows 10 allows users to install desktop apps directly. However there is not enough information yet.

As to your question, there is really no such thing as Windows 7 application. Maybe you made your application on Windows 7, but it probably runs on Vista, Windows 8, and 10. You just have to test it. It can get certified for Windows 10, but I don't think it will be the same way as Windows 8.

Problems with certification kit: Make sure the your application is completely uninstall from your computer, including app installation folders and app registry keys. Run the test again and make sure the program was installed.

Comment: In times of the Windows Software Logo Program there was a benefit of certifying applications even nobody thought about apps and stores. It may be as simple as a statement "See my program is listed on Microsoft's website of certified programs", so you can be sure it fulfills at least a few requirements defined by Microsoft. IIRC is was also a requirement to have such an application to become Microsoft Gold Partner.